# How to use transform.rotate properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my code for player movement in Unity:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float _rotateSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private AudioClip _moveClip, _loseClip;

    [SerializeField] private GameplayManager _gm;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _explosionPrefab;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            SoundManager.Instance.PlaySound(_moveClip);
            _rotateSpeed *= -1f;
        }
    }


    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.Rotate(0, 0, _rotateSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Obstacle"))
        {
            Instantiate(_explosionPrefab, transform.GetChild(0).position, Quaternion.identity);
            SoundManager.Instance.PlaySound(_loseClip);
            _gm.GameEnded();
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, the object doesn't move because the transform is not working as I expect it to work and I cannot figure out why, so any help would be great, thanks. The object does rotate around X and Y axis, but not around the Z axis. However, another object with the same rotation command does rotate properly.

Comment: Do you have _rotateSpeed assigned by some non-zero value in inspector?

Comment: Btw is there a special reason why doing this in `FixedUpdate`?

Comment: The value is non zero, when the object is inside its parent 2D Rigid Body it doesn't move with its parent, but on its own, it does move. Do you know a reason for that maybe?

Answer (score 0):

[`Transform.Rotate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) has an [optional parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments#optional-arguments)

> **relativeTo**
> Determines whether to rotate the GameObject either locally to the GameObject or relative to the Scene in world space.

By default (if you don't pass it) this parameter is `Space.Self`.

So if you rather want to apply the rotation in absolute world space you need to pass in

```
transform.Rotate(0, 0, _rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
```

Comment: FIXED
I only had to change the Sprite Sort Point inside the Sprite Renderer to pivot.